# Fetch Array - Combine Some Results in CSV

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

I'm taking results from a SQL database and outputting it to a CSV using the following code...

```
while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    fputcsv($handle, array(
        'admin',
        'base',
        'Default',
        'simple',
        '2', 
        $row['part_id'],
        $row['part_id'],
        $row['price'],
        $row['list_price'],
        $row['core'],
        $row['weight'],
        $row['height'],
        $row['length'],
        $row['width'],
        $row['popularity'],
        $row['qty'],
        $row['description_line_two'],
        $row['detailed_description'],
        $row['note'],
        $row['YearID'],
        $row['MakeID'],
        $row['ModelID'],
        $row['aspiration'],
        $row['bed_length'],
        $row['bed_type'],
        $row['body_num_doors'],
        $row['body_type'],
        $row['brake_abs'],
        $row['brake_system'],
        $row['cylinder_head_type'],
        $row['drive_type'],
        $row['engine_base'],
        $row['engine_designation'],
        $row['engine_version'],
        $row['engine_vin'],
        $row['fuel_delivery_type'],
        $row['fuel_delivery_subtype'],
        $row['fuel_system_design'],
        $row['fuel_type'],
        $row['mfr_body_code'],
        $row['region'],
        $row['steering_system'],
        $row['steering_type'],
        $row['submodel'],
        $row['transmission_control_type'],
        $row['transmission_num_speeds'],
        $row['transmission_type'],
        $row['valves_per_engine'],
        $row['wheel_base']
    ));
}
```

In the data, there are several instances where the part ID will be the same in several rows and the other fields (like year, make, model) would be different. What I'm hoping to do is to consolidate the data. In other words, where the part_id is consistent among two or more rows, I'd like to combine some of the other fields (for example year, make, model) into one row.

In other words, it's currently like this...

```
Part ID    Year    Make    Model
0001       2013    Suzuki  NA
0001       2012    Acura   NA
0001       2011    Hyundai Elantra
```

I'd like it to be like...

```
Part ID    Year              Make                      Model
0001       2013,2012,2011    Suzuki, Acura, Hyundai    NA, Elantra
```

Is this at all possible? If so, how would I go about doing it?

I'm open to a QUERY to manipulate the data in the database before it's fetched if that helps!

Comment: Could you do a `group_concat` grouped by `part id` in your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_table
SELECT 'admin' as custom1,'base' as custom2,part_id,year... etc
FROM original_table
WHERE 1;
```

Then you would want to select your stuff from there, and put the grouping in:

```
SELECT part_id, custom1, GROUP_CONCAT(year) as year
FROM tmp_table
WHERE 1
GROUP BY part_id
```

Not sure of the structure or the grouping, but a little bit of googling and reference searching should fill the gaps.  The concept is there, what you are looking for is the GROUP_CONCAT feature of MySQL (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: Thank you! In one example, the following is used in the query...

    SELECT id,GROUP_CONCAT(client_id) FROM services WHERE id = 3 GROUP BY id;

What if the ID is dynamic? Could it just group any duplicates?

Comment: That's where creating the tmp_table part comes in.  You need to make sure the tmp_table captures all the data you want to report on.  If you need to build it from multiple sources you can do that before fetching with the select query.  The group concat will only concatonate multiple fields if there are multiple rows matching your grouping.  So if you had only 1 row with part_id it will show it as normal